# Python 3.1 number guessing game higher or lower loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the process of learning Python using the book 'Python Programming for the Absolute Beginner Third Edition' and struggling with a challenge that has been set.

I have to create a Number Guessing program where the player picks a number and the program tries to guess it by picking a random number then using higher or lower questions to get closer to the number. I've got most of it figured out but I'm struggling with the higher or lower loop. The trouble I'm having is that i can't get the program to not go above or below it's second to last guess i.e.

My number is 78
computer picks 50
i say higher
computer picks 80
i say lower
computer can then pick 12 (when i don't want it going below 50.

I'm using Python 3.1

Here is a copy of the code.

```
import random

computer_tries = 0
player_number = None
computer_guess = random.randint(1, 100)

print(
    """
    Welcome Player to the fabulous number guessing game.
    Please allow me to show you my incredible deduction skills
    """)

question = None
while question != ("yes"):
    question = input("Has the player picked a number? ")
    question = question.lower()
    if question == "yes":
        print("\nI will now guess your number!!!\n")
        while player_number == None:
            computer_tries += 1
            print(computer_guess, "\n")
            confirmation = input("Is this the correct number? ")
            confirmation = confirmation.lower()
            if confirmation == "yes":
                player_number = computer_guess
                if computer_tries < 2:
                    print("I did it! I guessed your number was", computer_guess,
                           "and it only \ntook me", computer_tries,
                           "try to get it right!")
                else:
                    print("I did it! I guessed your number was", computer_guess,
                           "and it only \ntook me", computer_tries,
                           "tries to get it right!")
            else:
                higher_lower = None
                while higher_lower not in ("higher", "lower"):
                    higher_lower = input("Is my guess higher or lower"
                                + " than your number? ")
                    higher_lower = higher_lower.lower()
                    if higher_lower == "higher":
                        higher = computer_guess
                        computer_guess = random.randint(higher, 101)
                    elif higher_lower == "lower":
                        lower = computer_guess
                        computer_guess = random.randint(0, lower)
                    else:
                        print("Please choose either higher or lower.")



input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit")
```

Thanks in advance for any help you folks can give.

Ally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the following problems with your code:

1. your random number generators are bound only on one side of the number spectrum, e.g. `random.randint(0, lower)` - so it's ignoring the `higher` bound. Similarly for `computer_guess = random.randint(higher, 101)`.
2. I suggest you initialise `higher` and `lower`.
3. Some debug helps :)

Here's the working code:

```
import random

computer_tries = 0
player_number = None
computer_guess = random.randint(1, 100)

print(
    """
    Welcome Player to the fabulous number guessing game.
    Please allow me to show you my incredible deduction skills
    """)

question = None
lower = 0 # initial lower guess
higher = 101  # initial higher guess
while question != ("yes"):
    question = input("Has the player picked a number? ")
    question = question.lower()
    if question == "yes":
        print("\nI will now guess your number!!!\n")
        while player_number == None:
            computer_tries += 1
            print(computer_guess, "\n")
            confirmation = input("Is this the correct number? ")
            confirmation = confirmation.lower()
            if confirmation == "yes":
                player_number = computer_guess
                if computer_tries < 2:
                    print("I did it! I guessed your number was", computer_guess,
                           "and it only \ntook me", computer_tries,
                           "try to get it right!")
                else:
                    print("I did it! I guessed your number was", computer_guess,
                           "and it only \ntook me", computer_tries,
                           "tries to get it right!")
            else:
                higher_lower = None
                while higher_lower not in ("higher", "lower"):
                    higher_lower = input("Is my guess higher or lower"
                                + " than your number? ")
                    higher_lower = higher_lower.lower()
                    if higher_lower == "higher":
                        higher = computer_guess
                        computer_guess = random.randint(lower+1, higher-1)
                    elif higher_lower == "lower":
                        lower = computer_guess
                        computer_guess = random.randint(lower+1, higher-1)
                    else:
                        print("Please choose either higher or lower.")
                    print("DEBUG: number must be " + str(lower) + " < x < " + str(higher))


input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit")
```

Comment: I just seen I never thanked you for this which is poor form. So, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome; That's what the upvote & accept as answer buttons are there for, unless there's anything special/specific :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are never storing the upper and lower bounds to the possible numbers. In your example, as soon as your program picks 50 and you say "higher", you need to store somewhere the information that "the number is definitely higher than 50". The same goes for when you answer "lower".

Answer (score 1):

You have to store something like min_comp_guess and max_comp_guess
Then, when you are about to "guess" number you have to generate it for a valid range (obviously min_comp_guess up to max_comp_guess).

I'm always second! :)

Answer (score 0):

I may be completely wrong but whilst testing your code I found that by choosing the programs number was higher than my chosen number it would increase the number instead or a presumable decrease, not making it any closer to the number I had guessed. A similar higher/lower program I created had the same problem, to fix the problem I simply switched the more than and less than signs around, hopefully you find this helpful and could apply this to your program.